# This is my current way of writing to a file. However, I can't do UTF-8?

Tags: python, file, encoding, utf-8

```
f = open("go.txt", "w")
f.write(title)
f.close()
```

What if "title" is in japanese/utf-8? How do I modify this code to be able to write "title" without having the ascii error?

Edit: Then, how do I read this file in UTF-8?

Comment: If you are using Python 2.x and title refers to a str object, it's hard to see how you could be getting an error. If it's a python 2.x unicode object or a 3.x str object, then it's not "in anything/utf-8". Please say whether you are using Python 2.X or 3.X. Please show the code that triggers the error. Show the exact error message that you get. In general, please don't act like this is your first question; it's your 554th!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[How to use UTF-8](http://evanjones.ca/python-utf8.html):

```
import codecs

# ...
# title is a unicode string
# ...

f = codecs.open("go.txt", "w", "utf-8")
f.write(title)

# ...

fileObj = codecs.open("go.txt", "r", "utf-8")
u = fileObj.read() # Returns a Unicode string from the UTF-8 bytes in the file
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on whether you want to insert a [Unicode UTF-8 byte order mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8), of which the only way I know of is to open a normal file and write:

```
import codecs

f = open('go.txt', 'wb')
f.write(codecs.BOM_UTF8)
f.write(title.encode('utf-8')
f.close()
```

Generally though, I don't want to add a UTF-8 BOM and the following will suffice though:

```
import codecs

f = codecs.open('go.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
f.write(title)
f.close()
```

Comment: You can also use the 'utf-8-sig' codec.  It writes a BOM when writing and removes it (if necessary) when reading.